# Why didn't Bucky remove or paint over his red star?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

I was watching *Captain America: Civil War* and it occurred to me that Bucky still has a red star on his metal arm.

Shouldn't this symbol be a painful reminder to him of things that he has done in the past? Why has he not painted over it or scraped it off? I heard that in the comics he had painted over it at some point. Is there any reason that he hasn't in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Comment: I'm unsure about spoilers so I'm sorry if my spoiler tag or vagueness was unnecessary. I'm open to revisions if my question doesn't contain spoilers. I'm not really aware of if this has significance or not.

Comment: I can't think of any plot points in Civil War where the presence of the star has any impact whatsoever. This would be a spoiler for Winter Solider, but I think that's been out long enough to not worry about it. Personally I'd put the "spoilers" back into the title so it's perfectly clear what the (otherwise good) question is.

Comment: @Ixrec ok, if others agree I'll add <character name> and <symbol> to the title. I'm new to this site so I'm unfamiliar with what you guys consider to be "spoilery enough" so to speak.

Comment: The question is clear enough as is. I'm not saying you shouldn't edit, feel free if you'd like. But I wouldn't worry about it being unclear.

Comment: I would think that the star is the least of many painful reminders of his past. What is the point of removing the star if you still have the metal arm that means the same thing?

Comment: What's wrong with having a reminder of what you did in the past? Perhaps it's his point of strength to never return there.

Comment: Personally I'd paint over it because I wouldn't want to carry around a symbol representing a dark time in my past that might lead people to believe that I'm on the wrong side. But that's just me. I'm curious to know if Bucky had a specific reason or if this is just one of those things that hasn't changed because the filmmakers didn't feel like spending time to address it.

Comment: Having watched the movie now, at no point does Bucky appear to be very greatly pained by the past, certainly not to the point of wanting to erase his past. Whether this is an issue in the comics, it never enters in to the plot of the movie.

Comment: Ironically, the star doesn't even make sense in the MCU given that the Winter Soldier was made by HYDRA instead of the Soviet Union. I guess they considered it an iconic look for the character, though, and having a green octopus/skull just wouldn't be the same.

Comment: That metal arm is a highly advanced piece of tech that bucky has no idea how to maintain, do you really think he should be messing with it?

Comment: Maybe he kept it exactly **because** it's a reminder of the past?

Comment: @Omegacron - The star was probably purposely put there by HYDRA to make him appear as a Soviet operative. That's, like, their entire M.O. during that era, be the puppet masters behind more public organizations.

Comment: He can't see it from where he's standing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of the Red Star on Bucky's arm doesn't exactly have any kind of significant "backstory"... other than that he is the "Winter Soldier", suggesting himself as a Russian operative. This is similar to why Deadpool wears red ("So the bad guys don't see me bleed") or why Batman dresses as a bat ("I must become what I fear"). It's merely a symbol of what his character is, so removing it would pretty much just make him "That dude with the metal arm" (and in my opinion, "Winter Soldier" has a better ring to it).

As for any in-universe reason as to why he doesn't remove it, without any input from the writers, there's very little we can use. That said, there are a few things we can use to ascertain some form of reasoning.

1. **Bucky's state of mind.** Bucky has been brainwashed, and as we saw in the movies, how easily it was for him to fall back in line. With a state of mind as fragile as his own, he would need something to focus on, in order to keep himself grounded when his mind starts to slip. You might say the arm itself would act as that anchor, but when you've lived for 60+ years with such an appendage, you'd be hard put imagining what it would be like without it. The star, on the other hand, could work as that anchor.
2. **It is a reminder.** Once free of his mind control, Bucky regrets what he did while under mind control. He knows it wasn't his will that made him do it, but now that he has control of himself, he wants to change what the star stands for. It's like a scar - a bad reminder that you can take a lesson from, and make sure you make a better choice.

The only other option is a little less exciting - the star is painted on with special paint, staining the metal itself. Removing it would likely require filing or even the use of acid, and doing that could compromise the whole arm... which nobody wants.